# How to write a sql command according to many textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have 4 TextBoxes in my page and i wanna to write sql command code according to the entered parameters. Users choose at least to fill one textbox or  more.
so i need a code to select form database in function of textboxes filled out.
it's a filter function to filter from database using parameters

Comment: You have to tell us more. What have you tried, what was the problem? I assume that you'vew read some tutorials about ADO.NET and the documentation on `SqlCommand` and sql-parameters. What part did you not understand?

Comment: the problem is not all textboxes should be filled.

Comment: But what is the problem with that?

Comment: @AmineAntri: So you want to check whether or not the user has filled all TextBoxes? Use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text)` for all.

Comment: no, the user have to fill at least one TextBox or more
i'm looking for fucntion to check what textBoxes are filled to filter data

Comment: i'm looking for specific function, i can use " if..else " but this takes alot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Dim sql As New StringWriter()

    sql.WriteLine("Select col1, col2 , col3")
    sql.WriteLine("From yourtable ")
    sql.WriteLine("Where 1 =1 ")
    f Txt1.Text.Length > 0 Then
        sql.WriteLine("and col1 Like '%" + Txt1.Text + "%'")
    End If

    If Txt2.Text.Length > 0 Then
        sql.WriteLine("and col2 '%" + Txt2.Text + "%'")
    End If

    If Txt3.Text.Length > 0 Then
        sql.WriteLine("and col3 Like '%" + Txt3.Text + "%'") 
    End If
    If Txt4.Text.Length > 0 Then
        sql.WriteLine("and col4 Like '%" + Txt4.Text + "%'") 
    End If
```

for c#

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
StringWriter sql = new StringWriter();

sql.WriteLine("Select col1, col2 , col3");

sql.WriteLine("From yourtable ");

sql.WriteLine("Where 1 =1 ");


if ((Txt1.Text.Length > 0)) {
sql.WriteLine(("and col1 Like \'%" 


 + (Txt1.Text + "%\'")));

}

if ((Txt2.Text.Length > 0)) {
sql.WriteLine(("and col2 \'%" 


 + (Txt2.Text + "%\'")));
}
if ((Txt3.Text.Length > 0)) {
sql.WriteLine(("and col3 Like \'%" 
+ (Txt3.Text + "%\'")));
}
if ((Txt4.Text.Length > 0)) {
sql.WriteLine(("and col4 Like \'%" 
+ (Txt4.Text + "%\'")));
}
```

and then send the sql as command 
if there is any syntax missing or any comma so make it correct coz i write it without the IDE

Comment: This is tagged as C# - not VB

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Please read up on [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use if conditions.

```
  private void BuildCommand()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must fill out text box 1");
                return;
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine("select column1, column2, column3");
            sb.AppendLine("from MyTableName");
            sb.AppendLine("Where");
            sb.AppendLine(textBox1.Text);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(textBox2.Text);    
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(textBox3.Text);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(textBox4.Text);
            }
        }
```

Now the problem with doing it like this is you open yourself up for SQL injection.  This is a dangerous pattern and should not be used!!!!

This is a better way:

```
 private void BuildCommand()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must fill out text box 1");
                return;
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var sqlparams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            sb.AppendLine("select column1, column2, column3");
            sb.AppendLine("from MyTableName");
            sb.AppendLine("Where");
            sb.AppendLine("param1 = @param1");
            sqlparams.Add("param1", textBox1.Text);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
            {
                sb.AppendLine("and param2 = @param2");
                sqlparams.Add("param2", textBox2.Text);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
            {
                sb.AppendLine("and param3 = @param3");
                sqlparams.Add("param3", textBox3.Text);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
            {
                sb.AppendLine("and param4 = @param4");
                sqlparams.Add("param4", textBox4.Text);
            }

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString());
            foreach (var sqlparam in sqlparams)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlparam.Key, sqlparam.Value);
            }
        }
```